# how to get resource's availability using web api?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

CRM 2016 exposes odata/web api, and has [functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309638.aspx) and [actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607829.aspx) out of the box.

With the organization service, we can issue a request [like this:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.searchrequest.aspx)

```
// Create the van required resource object.
RequiredResource vanReq = new RequiredResource
{
    ResourceId = _vanId,
    ResourceSpecId = _specId
};

// Create the appointment request.
AppointmentRequest appointmentReq = new AppointmentRequest
{
    RequiredResources = new RequiredResource[] { vanReq },
    Direction = SearchDirection.Backward,
    Duration = 60,
    NumberOfResults = 10,
    ServiceId = _plumberServiceId,
    // The search window describes the time when the resouce can be scheduled.
    // It must be set.
    SearchWindowStart = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
    SearchWindowEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToUniversalTime(),
    UserTimeZoneCode = 1
};

// Verify whether there are openings available to schedule the appointment using this resource              
SearchRequest search = new SearchRequest
{
    AppointmentRequest = appointmentReq
};
SearchResponse searched = (SearchResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(search);

if (searched.SearchResults.Proposals.Length > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Openings are available to schedule the resource.");
}
```

**Is it possible to mimic this functionality using functions/action or any other odata functionality?**

I believe that the request should be something like this:

```
crmOrg/api/v8.1/Search(AppointmentRequest=@request)?@request=
```

However, I'm not sure how to encode the rest of the request.

Comment: `_serviceProxy.Execute` will send a request over `http` (tcp port 80) to the end point (using HTTP GET). You can capture this request on your PC with either a network sniffer or with a debugging tool. I prefer [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), you can configure this to be a proxy between your app and the end point and it will capture traffic. Then it is just a matter of reading the URL for each specific request you want to mimic. So create request in c# and capture generated URL in Fiddler (*also it is a free tool, I have no affiliation with telerik*).

Comment: Probably you can compose the fetchxml & issue a web api call like this: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmcustomization/archive/2016/11/01/use-fetchxml-to-retrieve-data-from-ms-crm-2016-using-web-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter goes like:

```
http://yourcrm.org/org/api/data/v8.1/Search(AppointmentRequest=@ar)/?@ar={SearchWindowStart:%272017-01-01%27,Duration:60,NumberOfResults:10}
```

it is url encoded json of serialized `AppointmentRequest` class.

```
{
  SearchWindowStart:'2017-01-01',
  Duration: 60,
  NumberOfResults:10,
  etc...
}
```

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.appointmentrequest.aspx

ODATA reference: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/04-06-function-parameter-support/

Comment: Reference docs for this particular API are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/search?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9